# Adapting my chat app to work with rooms in socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I have this simple chat application, and I'm looking to adapt it so the users can use the 4 different rooms I created.
I'll try to explain how it works first, and I need to be guided, what would be the steps I need to take in order to make it work?(considering I'm a beginner) I've tried a lot of things but it always came out really buggy.

**Client side:**

```
//Get the room name out of the URL and send it to the server
function getRoomName() {
        let roomName = window.location.toString();
        if(roomName.includes('#') === true){
            roomName = roomName.split("#");
            roomName.splice(0, 1);
            roomName = roomName.toString();
            // Join room
            socket.emit('joinRoom', roomName);
        }
    }

//Here I am changing the URL when clicking on a room button (I got one of these for each button)
proiectFinalRoom.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        window.location.href='#proiectFinal'; 
        roomNameEdit.innerHTML = "#PROIECT-FINAL";  
    })

 sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        sendMessage();
    })

    //Here I am sending the message to the server
    function sendMessage(){
        if(messageInput.value === ""){
            return;
        } else {
                   //Calling the getRoomName function (when sending a message)
            getRoomName();

            const text = messageInput.value;
            socket.emit('message', text);
        displayMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Server side:**

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('joinRoom', function(roomName){
        //Join room
        socket.join(roomName);

        //Send messages
        socket.on('message', (message) => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomName).emit('message', `${message}`);          
        });
    });
});
```

This is the stage I am at right now, and It is definetely not working as it should. I already read a lot of articles about socket.io and rooms, but since english is not my first language I find it hard to understand where the problem is in my code.

Comment: You mentioned that your code is very buggy. Could you list some of the bugs you encounter? It'd be easier to help you that way.

Comment: To be completely honest I don't really understand what is going on. To me, it looks like it creates a new user every time the getRoomName() is called. (so every time you send a message)
After connecting to a few rooms, messages get really messy. You receive messages even if you are not connected to the same room as the sender, you receive the same message multiple times...

Comment: Or maybe they get connected to the same room multiple times? (I don't even know if that's possible)

Answer (score 0):

I think your Server side "message" call might be too nested. I would do something like this (keeping in mind that sockets maintains a collection of rooms):

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('joinRoom', function(roomName){
        //Join room
        socket.join(roomName);
    });

    //Send messages
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
        var room = getRoom(socket);
        socket.to(room).emit('message', `${message}`);          
    });
});

function getRoom(socket) {
  var room;
  for (let aRoom of socket.rooms) {
    if (aRoom !== socket.id) {
      room = aRoom;
    }
  }
  return room;
}
```

On the Client Side you use something like this. This way you only join the room once (I'm using React here):

```
  const [room, setRoom] = useState<string>();
  ...
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!room) {
      if (param) {
        var myRoom = param['room'];
        if (!myRoom) {
          socket.emit("ping");
        } else {
          socket.emit('join room', myRoom);
          setRoom(myRoom);
        }
      } else {
        socket.emit("ping");
      }
    }
  }, [room, param, socket]);
```

Comment: It didn't change anything. 
To be completely honest I don't really understand what is going on. To me, it looks like it creates a new user every time the getRoomName() is called. (so every time you send a message) After connecting to a few rooms, messages get really messy. You receive messages even if you are not connected to the same room as the sender, you receive the same message multiple times,  or maybe they get connected to the same room multiple times? (I don't even know if that's possible)

Comment: I think you're calling your getRoomName() method too much. It really only needs to be called once. I updated my answer to include how I make I've only done it once (I'm using React in my example)

Comment: Any way you can convert this to javascript? I've never used React before so I'm not sure how to implement this.